How to reconstruct an image from s-parameters in MATLAB with datasets are 37 files colleting from 0-360 degree angle (10 degree of increment)?
How to reconstruct an image from s-parameters in MATLAB ? My dataset are 37 files colleting from 0-360 degree angle (10 degree of increment), all data collected from VNA
I have a set of data which is the s-parameter (s11) for the object rotating from 0-360 degree (10 degree of increment), each dataset consisting of 3 columns (180×3). The first column represents the frequency and the second column is the real of S11, the third column is the imagine of S11. I need to use these data to reconstruct an image using MATLAB but I have no idea how to do it.
% Load and prepare data
num_angles = 36; % Number of angles (0 to 360 with 10-degree increments)
time_domain_signals = [];

for angle_idx = 1:num_angles
    filename = sprintf('%d-VF.CSV', (angle_idx-1)*10);
    data = readmatrix(filename);
    
    % Extract data
    frequency = data(:, 1);
    real_S11 = data(:, 2);
    imag_S11 = data(:, 3);
    
    % Combine real and imaginary parts into complex S11
    S11 = real_S11 + 1i * imag_S11;
    
    % Convert to time-domain using IFFT
    time_domain_signal = ifft(S11);
    
    % Store the magnitude
    time_domain_signals = [time_domain_signals; abs(time_domain_signal(:))'];
end

% Calculate the total number of elements in time_domain_signals
total_elements = numel(time_domain_signals);

% Set one dimension to [] to automatically calculate based on the number of elements
% Assume that the image is a 2D image; the following sets the number of columns and lets MATLAB calculate the number of rows:
num_columns = 77; % This is just an example, adjust based on data
reconstructed_image = reshape(time_domain_signals, [], num_columns);

% Display the reconstructed image
imagesc(reconstructed_image);
colormap('gray');
colorbar;
title('Reconstructed Image from S11 Data');
xlabel('X-axis');
ylabel('Y-axis');

